# Yii AuthManager schema and types

Tags: mysql, rbac, yii

I'm confused about the Yii's AuthManager in general and the schema used for DB tables.

1. The **type** field in the **AuthItem** table can be only between 0 and 2 ( Role=2, Task=1, Operation=0 ) ?
2. Could you make me an example of what I can find stored in the **bizrule** and **data** fields using the blog used in the tutorial ?
3. The **userid** field must be a varchar ?

This schema ( for MySQL ) generates any conflict ?

```
CREATE TABLE `AuthItem` (
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255),
  `bizrule` text,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `AuthItemChild` (
  `parent` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `child` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent`,`child`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `AuthItem` (`name`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`child`) REFERENCES `AuthItem` (`name`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `AuthAssignment` (
  `itemname` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bizrule` text,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemname`,`userid`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`itemname`) REFERENCES `AuthItem` (`name`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `User` (`userid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes **type** field have to be one of [those values](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/auth/CDbAuthManager.php#L428).

   ```
   0: operation, 1: task, 2: role
   ```
2. **bizrule** can be any string that [holds an executable PHP code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/auth/CAuthManager.php#L148) which [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)s `false` or `true` and [ends with a semicolon](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20eval%20semicolon&ie=UTF-8). And **data** should be a [string contains some serialized value(s)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/auth/CDbAuthManager.php#L342), you can use them by operating `$data` variable in your **bizrule**.
3. **userid** field can be of any type I think, but default `varchar` implementation [comes](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/auth/CDbAuthManager.php#L66) from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/interfaces.php#L305).

Answer (score 0):

You only have three different types of authentication items; roles, tasks, and operations. The reality is that they can be treated virtually the same and the distinction is more for design than implementation. The biz rule is used to determine whether a user has access or not or in other words granularity to the permissions. For example a user might have permission to create  a user, but only a basic user, not an admin. This is the kind of granularity the bizrules can give you. Spend time on the design of the roles and access and the auth implementation will be pretty straight forward. This playlist on youtube gives a better example.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fGUtvwofU8&list=PLdfhvjWV26rQBM9gUAPG1BnTrDGsReQSr